# url not found when debugging Zend Framework app in Eclipse PDT

Tags: debugging, zend-framework, eclipse-pdt

I installed both Zend Debugger and XDebug in Eclipse PDT but did not succeed in debugging my Zend Framework application.

When I create a new PHP page in 'Run > Debug Configurations' and enter myproject/public/index.php under 'file' and click 'DEBUG' my browser responds with 'the requested URL 'myproject/public/index.php' was not found on this server.

That is correct because on my server the url would be myproject (or myproject/index or myproject/index/index). Entering this url in the screen mentioned above is not accepted however as it is not a php file in my application.

As apparently nobody has a similar problem I am probably completely on the wrong track. Anyone to enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Debug Configurations dialog, at the bottom, you should see a URL field.  Set this to the url - eg. `myproject/index`.  Leave the `File` setting as `myproject/public/index.php`.

The domain in the URL field at the bottom will probably be set to the default `localhost`.  If you need to change this, click `Configure` next to PHP Server at the top, and change `Base URL`.

This is all assuming XDebug.  It may work the same for Zend Debugger, but I use XDebug.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Indeed for XDebug, cannot get Zend Debugger to connect to the IP of my computer (where the webserver resides as well).